# Oracle SQL - Cannot remove index usage by hints?

Tags: sql, oracle, hint

This was a challenge from uni test.
The requierment was to solve It using hints.

---

I'm trying to complete a query where I want it to use nested loops and NO indices. For this, I wrote the query:

```
select /*+ USE_NL(fulltable) NO_INDEX(fulltable) */  sum(QUANTITY) summarized from
    (select /*+ USE_NL(sz1, sz2, c1) NO_INDEX(sz1, sz2, c1) */ distinct *     
     from SZTABLE sz1 
          natural join SZTABLE2 sz2
          natural join CTABLE c1
          where city= 'Newark' and COLOR= 'red') fulltable;
```

However, upon explaining the query and writing it out, I get:

```
SELECT STATEMENT +  + 
  SORT + AGGREGATE + 
    VIEW +  + 
      HASH + UNIQUE + 
        NESTED LOOPS +  + 
          NESTED LOOPS +  + 
            HASH JOIN +  + 
              JOIN FILTER + CREATE + :BF0000
                TABLE ACCESS + FULL + CTABLE
              VIEW +  + VW_DTP_5C333E12
                HASH + UNIQUE + 
                  JOIN FILTER + USE + :BF0000
                    TABLE ACCESS + FULL + SZTABLE
            INDEX + UNIQUE SCAN + SZO_SZKOD
          TABLE ACCESS + BY INDEX ROWID + SZTABLE2
```

Apparently, the query still uses indices, even though I explicitly asked it not to. How can I fix this? Why is there still and index used for ROWID?

(The plan was written out by the snippet below.)

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', 2*(level-1))||operation||' + '||options||' + '||object_name terv
FROM plan_table
START WITH id = 0 AND statement_id = 'plan1'
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id AND statement_id = 'plan1'
ORDER SIBLINGS BY position;
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't use `natural join`.  It makes the query very hard to understand because the join keys are not clear.

Comment: I understand, but that's not the point of the question. I wonder why I can't make the index usage disappear.

Comment: Please post the structure of your tables

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? May be exist more elegant solution depending on source problem.

Comment: Might be, it was just a test question at uni. Do this and this by NOT using indices and using nested loops. I just couldn't make all the index uses disappear, and I wonder how I could do it.

Comment: You can try `ALTER INDEX index_name INVISIBLE;` - as long as you are not asked to use hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange question but you can get all your index on tables involving into query and execute this:

```
alter index <Index_Name> unusable
```

Or rewrite query

```
select sum(QUANTITY) summarized from
    (select distinct *     
     from SZTABLE sz1 
          join SZTABLE2 sz2 on sz1.id+0 = sz2.id+0 --put your join condition, cause I don't know you table columns
          join CTABLE c1 on c.id+0 = sz2.id+0 --put your join condition
          where city || ''= 'Newark' and COLOR|| ''= 'red') fulltable;
```

Look at combination

```
z1.id+0 
city || ''
```

Results are the same but CBO see expr and can't find it in index

Comment: Yeah I know, it was in a test at uni, we were supposed to solve this by using hints.

Comment: @lte__ Hints smt can't be catch. Can you modify query a little? Means rewrite join condition or predicate?

Answer (score 1):

You had syntax errors.

- use_nl requires multiple tables to be separated by spaces and not commas.
- no_index works on a single table.

Please try, for the inner query.

```
use_nl(sz1 sz2 c1) no_index(sz1) no_index(sz2) no_index(c1)
```

You can remove anything else

Comment: TBH this was a test question at uni, and I was supposed to use nested loops and no indices. So this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support.

Comment: I was refering to the uni test not this SO post :-)

Comment: I still get 

`INDEX + RANGE SCAN + SZT_SZKOD`
`TABLE ACCESS + BY INDEX ROWID + SZTABLE2`

Comment: I thought you said the solution should use hints. Have a chance to test the updated answer?